# htaccess hide subdirectories in ALL pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So i have changed my htaccess file to hide my subdirectory in the main url but any requests to other pages, they return in the url with the subdirectory now listed.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my_site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my_site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !2013/
RewriteRule (.*) /2013/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So when i go to www.my_site.com the subdirectory is hidden as it should. But if i hit another page through my sites navigation the url will now show the subdirectory in the URL.

Is there any way to hide that directory in ALL situations?

Comment: I don't think this is easy to do solely via htaccess. Take a look at [these instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) and see if they're something you can implement.